# Loop prints more than once

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to convert from lower to uppercase. I know they are other easier ways to do this, but I want something else. It seems that the program prints out the users input more than once, so I am almost 100% sure it's the loop. But I can't find where the problem is.

```
String a = input.nextLine();
String c = "";
int b = a.length();

for (int i = 0 ; i < b; i++)
{
    if (a.charAt(i) >= 97 && a.charAt(i) <= 122)
    {
        c = c + a;
        System.out.println(c.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code logic wasn't totally right, I mean why would you add the content of `a` to `c`? Doesn't make sense, and you excluded the letters *a* and *z* in your `if`.

```
String a = input.nextLine();
String c = "";
int b = a.length();
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    if (a.charAt(i) >= 97 && a.charAt(i) <= 122) {
        c = c + a.charAt(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(c.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user inputs "Hello" ? Do you really want the answer to be "ELLO" ?

Comment: How do you do that? " I'm new " :)

Comment: doesnt make sense, but thats what he is trying to accomplish here, i just helped him out...

Comment: Lets say I missed that part.

Comment: honestly i dont get it why dont you just use a.toUpperCase(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `c` in each iteration of the loop where the `if` is entered instead of just once, after it ends.

Comment: Umm so I print c outside of the loop? I don't think that will change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < b; i++)
{
    if (a.charAt(i) > 97 && a.charAt(i) < 122)
    {
        a = a.toUpperCase();
    }
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother going through the loop at all?

```
String a = input.nextLine();
System.out.println( a.toUpperCase();
```

will do what you want

If you want to invert the characters:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a);
for ( int i=0; i < sb.length(); i++ ) {
   char c = sb.charAt(i);
   if ( c.isLower() ) {
      sb.setCharAt(i,c.toUpper());
   } else if ( c.isUpper() ) {
      sb.setCharAt(i,c.toLower());
   }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yes i know they are more easier ways to do it as I mention, but when you want to swap you can't just do it like this.

Comment: I don't  know what you mean by "when you want to swap"

Comment: If I want the program to change all the lower to upper and the upper to lower this program wouldn't make that work.

Comment: For example if user inputs : HellO I want to swap it so it return hELLo

Comment: StringBuffer sb = new StringBufferr(a);
then loop through sb for each character:
if ( sb.charAt(I).isUpper() ) {
  sb.char:

Comment: Haven't learned that yet, but i would be glad to know learn what it is  "StringBuffer sb = new StringBufferr(a);"

Comment: SEE MY REVISESD ANSWER

Comment: @armin Note that your original method is extremely inefficient since you create an entire new string each time you execute the line "c = c + a"

Comment: OOOOOOOO so that's why it was repeating that much.